# Tool for adding index automatically to tex's files from a list

Tags: indexing, scripts, makeindex

Is there any dedicated tool (script or LaTeX's package) for adding the `\index` command (or other command) to many LaTeX's files?
The idea is to declare the list of the requested index such

```
Henri Bergson|Bergson, Henri
bergson|Bergson, Henri
```

The first word will be the pattern on which the `\index` command will be applied et the second will be the content of the `\index` command.

The idea will be also to avoid to applied the `\index` on certain case: for instance if the pattern is in a `\cite` command (`\cite{bergson}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I propose a small script for doing this. It is written in `shell` using `perl`.

It must be placed in a folder on which all the tex file are situated. A `list_index.txt` file must be placed at the same level of the script. In this file you can add on line per author with the following format:

```
Henri Bergson|Bergson, Henri|B
bergson|Bergson, Henri|B
charlie chaplin|Chaplin, Charlie
chaplin|Chaplin, Charlie
lilian gish|Gish, Lilian
gish|Gish, Lilian
```

The syntax must be:

- First column: the pattern on which you want to add an index entry
- Second column: the form on the index entry
- Third column (optional): the position you want in the index (if you want to force a specific location.

A `\newcommand` must be added in the head of the main latex: `\newcommand{\md}[2]{#1\index[perso]{#2}}` (must be adapted, here I used `indextools` package).

**How it works:**

Each time the pattern is find in the tex's files (unsensitive case), it is replace by the command `\md{<<pattern>>}{<< corresponding second column>>}`.
For example, ìn the text `bergson` will be replaced by  `\md{bergson}{B@Bergson, Henri}` and `charlie chaplin` will be replaced by `\md{bergson}{Chaplin, Charlie}`.

The script avoid to add `\md` command in inappropriate place such as `\cite`, `\footcite`, `footfullcite`, `\md`, `\ref`, `\pageref` and `\includegraphics`. This list must be adapted in the `perl` lines of the script.

**Bash's script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

listeIdx=list_index.txt
cmdIndex='\\md'

while IFS= read -r var || [ -n "$var" ]
do
  entryIx=`echo $var|cut -d'|' -f1`
  keyIx=`echo $var|cut -d'|' -f2`
  specIx=`echo $var|cut -d'|' -f3`
  #
  if [[ -z "${keyIx// }" ]];then
    echo $keyIx
    continue
    else
        echo -e "\n\nEntry: $entryIx || Key: $keyIx"
      for file in `ls *.tex`
      do
        if [ "$file" != "manuscrit.tex" -a "$file" != "Couverture.tex" -a "$file" != "resume.tex" -a "$file" != "titre.tex" ];then
            echo $file
            if [[ -z "${specIx// }" ]];then
                perl -i.bak -lpe 's/(\\pageref([^}]*)|\\ref([^}]*)|\\label([^}]*)|\\includegraphics([^}]*)|\\footfullcite([^}]*)|\\footcite([^}]*)|\\cite([^}]*)|\\md{(.*?)}([^}]*))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b'"${entryIx}"'\b/'"${cmdIndex}"'{$&}{'"$keyIx"'}/ig' $file
            else
                perl -i.bak -lpe 's/(\\pageref([^}]*)|\\ref([^}]*)|\\label([^}]*)|\\includegraphics([^}]*)|\\footfullcite([^}]*)|\\footcite([^}]*)|\\cite([^}]*)|\\md{(.*?)}([^}]*))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b'"${entryIx}"'\b/'"${cmdIndex}"'{$&}{'"$specIx"'\@'"$keyIx"'}/ig' $file
            fi
        fi
      done
    fi
done < $listeIdx
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded a one-line (powerful) script doing about the same, in a semi-automatic fashion, which I find very convenient to avoid adding misleading references. You just need to:

- put the following script in a file named `Makefile`
- ensure you have GNU Make installed, and ViM
- enter your searched items in a columnar text file (e.g. `list_names_1.csv`) like this:

```
Bergson;Bergson, Henri
Herder;Herder, Johann Gottfried
```

- run `make index-tagger INDEX=names LABELS=list_names_1.csv  TARGET=Chapters/Chapter01.tex` from the command line
- vim opens and cycles through every occurrence of each of your search terms, letting you either replace (type `y`) or ignore (type `n`) the occurrence of the search term with `Search Term\index[index_name]{Search Label}`.

```
# Makefile

#################################################################
#                        index-tagger recipe                    #
#                                                               #
# Inputs:                                                       #
# - name of LABELS csv file with "search;label" data            #
# - name of TARGET file that should be edited                   #
# - name of INDEX (e.g. 'noms')                                 #
#                                                               #
# Output:                                                       #
# - ranges through the CSV file                                 #
# - for each search;label pair, searches through the target     #
# - at each match, asks for replace confirmation in VIM         #
# - logs what has been done in a file                           #
#                                                               #
# Usage example:                                                #
# $ make index-tagger INDEX=names LABELS=list_names_1.csv TARGET=Chapters/Chapter01.tex
#                                                                #
##################################################################

index-tagger:
    cat $(LABELS) | sed -n "s-\(.*\);\(.*\)-\"vi \-c \'%s/\\\\(\\\\\\\\\\\\(sub\\\\)*section.*\\\\|caption\\\\(=\\\\)\\\\?{.*\\\\|\\\\\\\\cite%\\\\_..*\\\\|\\\\\\\\index\\\\[names\\\\]{[^}]*\\\\)\\\\@<\!\\\\<\\\\(\1\\\\)\\\\>/\1\\\\\\\\index[$(INDEX)]{\2}/gc\' \-c \'wq\' \"$(TARGET)\"; sleep .2; echo \"\\$$\(date\)\"\';$(INDEX);$(LABELS);$(TARGET);\0\' >> index_tagger.log\"-p" | xargs -o -I % sh -c '%'
```

PS. I just noticed the name of the index is hard-coded in the replace regex, I must have forgotten to fix that. Any improval on this is welcome.

PPS. Yeah, that's a **lot** of escapes!